# java linkedlist returns same element multi thread

Tags: java, multithreading, linked-list, thread-safety, synchronized

I want to add ***Packets*** read by my ***PacketHandler*** into an `LinkedList` to
save them with:

```
Packet toAdd = handler.handlePacket(socket.getInputStream());
synchronized (packetsRead) {
    packetsRead.addLast(toAdd);
    if (debug) {
       System.out.println(packetsRead.getLast().toString());
    }
}
```

and reading them with

```
synchronized (packetsRead) {
    if (packetsRead.size() > 0) {
        return packetsRead.pollFirst();
    }
}
```

with the debug method in the first method I can see that the
last item is never the same. So different Packets are added into my list.

But when I try to read them from a different thread I always got the same packets.

For example if there are 10 different packets in my list it would return the first one 10 times.

***How to make it thread safe?***

Comment: Why not use thread-safe implementations? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043948/thread-safe-linkedlist-alternate-use

Comment: Ups i synchronized it on the same object, i changed it to this for testing purposes. sorry

Comment: How do you access the list in you reading thread - are you sure you don't make a copy of the list every time to get always the first item?

Comment: i think it cannot be a copy of the list because it will only return
as often the same element as there are elements in the queue

Comment: Please show the definition of `packetsRead` and explain any other usage of it,  Your code looks fine here.

Answer (score 1):

Code must synchronize on the **same** object.

If this was done - and the rest of the program correct, and this was the only place the `LinkedList` was accessed - then it would work as expected, with or without threads.  If using the same object the synchronization blocks are not large enough and the posted code does not show the problem.

FWIW: See Matt's answer for some alternative thread-safe-by-design data structures. But note that these will *only* solve the problem if the issue was not using the same synchronized object.

Comment: synchronized on the same object it still won't work :/
i will try it with an LinkedBlockingQueue or synchronizedList

Comment: Then you are not showing the broken code and/or all access to the linked list - and switching to another structure will *not* fix the problem, which is not using a large enough threadsafe region/construct.

Comment: Well i told you that i am reading from another thread and "pollFirst" is always returning the same object.
i changed it for testing reasons to
Packet answer = packetsRead.pollFirst();
System.out.println(answer.toString());
return answer;
and it was always the same

Comment: @Michii So there are three probable  causes 1) the code is not synchronizing on the same object 2) that is not the effected code or; 3) the same 'answer' object is being modified and/or shared (or there is another problem with the test) such that it appears to 'always be the same'. Switching the data structure will not help with #2 or #3. Make sure to post a *minimal SSCCE*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a plain `LinkedList` for concurrent purposes:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally.

At the very least, use `Collections.synchronizedList()`as described in [the `LinkedList` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Even better: use a thread safe, concurrent data structure such as [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html), [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) or [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

Comment: While these will work, it doesn't address the problem.